# ghosts in my DOMDocument?

Tags: php, domdocument

Trying to simple xpath that was running, now show only empty nodes.

Source: any XML file. Suppose

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br" xml:lang="pt-br">
  <head> <meta charset="utf-8"/><title>test</title> </head>
  <body>
    <article id="etc"><p>Hello</p><p>Bye</p></article>
  </body>
</html>
```

I redo all, and here include a complete test:

```
$dom2 = new DOMDocument;
$dom2->Load($pathFile);
$xpath2 = new DOMXPath($dom2);
$entries = $xpath->query('//p');
// nothing here, all empty:
var_dump($entries);  // zero!
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    echo "Found {$entry->nodeValue},";
}
// by all here!  
foreach($dom2->getElementsByTagName('*') as $e )
  print "\n name={$e->nodeName}";  // all tags!
```

What is worng, **why xpath is not running?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an old problem with the W3C's DomDocument v1.0 standards. As [an old site commented](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html) about the XPath-beginners surprise,

> One of the commonly asked questions about (...) is: 
> *"Why nothing matched for my XPath expression which seems right to me?"*
> Common cause of these problems is not properly defining a namespace for XPath.

But beginners are right,  is an **ugly behaviour** for a "default thing"... So let's preserve the beginners good intuition about what is simple and good.

Is horrible to see a XPath that not seems what you need (what XML seems when its tags have no prefix). The tags are simple tags, need simple XPath.

### Reliable workaround

Fixing the ugly XPath-query's behaviour with the best solution. It is not trivial because root's `xmlns` attribute [is read-only](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1543187), so we need re-do DOM object by a new string XML:

```
$expTag = 'html';  // config expected tag-root
$expNs  = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml';  // config
// ...
$e = $dom->documentElement; // root node

// Validate input (as expecteds configs) and change tag root:
if ($e->nodeName==$expTag && $e->hasAttribute('xmlns') 
    && $e->getAttribute('xmlns')==$expNs) {
  // can't do $e->removeAttribute('xmlns') because is read-only!
  $xml = $dom->C14N(); // normalize quotes and remove repeateds
  $xml = preg_replace("#^<$expTag (.*?)xmlns=\"[^\"]+\"#", "<$expTag\$1", $xml);
  $dom = DOMDocument::LoadXML($xml);
} else 
     die("\n ERROR: something not expected.\n");
//...
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query('//p'); // perfect, now back simple to express XPath!
```

This solution must be used only when you have no limitations, as in [*digital preservation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_preservation) contexts.

The problem in other practical contexts is the high cost (CPU) of save/reload the full XML as string, and to be safe, yet more expensive  [C14N](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.c14n.php)  method, that prepares safe XML to the regular expression.

The use of C14N (good also for other things in a *digital preservation* context) is necessary to ensure the correct behaviour of the regular expression — strictly the `getAttribute()` method may be affected by an attribute duplication, but we can neglect this "second order" effect, or  transfer the checking to the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the your xml has a default namespace defined:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

So you need to register a namespace then search using namespaced tag names:

```
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$entries = $xpath->query('//x:p');
```

Comment: Yes, you show the point (!), now I will dream without ghosts... But let's see... So many sites and recommendations say that "default XHTML namespace `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`" (even for HTML5 as [html-polyglot](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-polyglot/))... Something **not make sense**:  namespace `x` is for `x:y`  tags, not for change default behaviour.

Comment: @PeterKrauss `x` in `registerNamespace` is an arbitrary identifier. You may use any identifier there, eg `peter`, so it would be `peter:p` :-) But yes, you must specify a namespace explicitly: that's why it is there in the very first place.

Comment: Yes, thanks (!)... So, this is the (ugly) law, we accept... Seems that a keyword here  is also *"qualified name"*, when `xmlns` attribute is defined. No matter for `foreach($dom2->getElementsByTagName('p') as $e )` (not needs *registerNamespace*), no prefix is used in the node tags (no `x:p`). The *qualified name* must be used only inside the XPath query.